# Check if checkbox with specific id is checked JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Please help me how to identify if a checkbox with specific id is checked/unchecked.

```
<input name="A" id="test" type="checkbox" value="A" /> 
<input name="B" id="test" type="checkbox" value="B" />
<input name="C" id="test1" type="checkbox" value="C" />
<input name="C" id="test1" type="checkbox" value="D" />
```

If i check the checkbox with id="test" and name="a", then the event should fire and otherwise it should not for rest of the checkbox with different id other than "test"

Please help

Comment: That html is not valid, id **must** be unique. You can use `data-` attributes for custom data and css classes to identify group of elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Element IDs in a given document **must** be unique! Hence, change your HTML to something like below and take a look at the script.

```js
$(function() {
    $(":checkbox").on("change", function() {
        //When the id is test1
        //And name is A
        //And it's checked
        if (this.id === "test1" && this["name"] === "A" && this.checked) {
            alert ("Checkbox with name A and ID test1 is checked");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="A" id="test1" type="checkbox" value="A" /> 
<input name="B" id="test2" type="checkbox" value="B" />
<input name="C" id="test3" type="checkbox" value="C" />
<input name="C" id="test4" type="checkbox" value="D" />
```

Comment: To be fair he could use a selector like `$('input[value="A"]')`.  No, I wouldn't recommend this, but if the HTML were from somewhere you couldn't change you could do that.

Answer (score 4):

Since you tag JQuery [you can find it helpful](https://jsfiddle.net/federicomassi/k7Lam0zh/2/)

```
AAA <input type="checkbox" id="test" />
BBB <input type="checkbox" id="test1" />
CCC <input type="checkbox" id="test2" />
```

and

```
$( "input" ).on( "click", function() {
  // for a specific one, but you can add a foreach cycle if you need more 
  if($('#test').is(":checked")){
      alert('is checked!');
  }else {
      alert('is NOT checked!');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Id's must be Unique.... otherwise when you use `document.getElementById();`

It will select First occurence of specific Id...

Instead implement like this..

```
<input name="A"  type="checkbox" value="A" /> 
<input name="B"  type="checkbox" value="B" />
<input name="C"  type="checkbox" value="C" />
<input name="C"  type="checkbox" value="D" />
```

and trigger a event on click oncheck box and use `document.getElementsByName('');`